# relative layout add view align below

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

So, I create view,set size and position and add it to RelativeLayout.It is added to the desired position.

```
    View fakeView = new View(getContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) view.getViewBounds().width(),
            (int) view.getViewBounds().height());
    // params.leftMargin = (int) view.getViewBounds().left;
    // params.topMargin = (int) view.getViewBounds().top;
    fakeView.setX((int) view.getViewBounds().left);
    fakeView.setY((int) view.getViewBounds().top);
    fakeView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80FFFFFF"));
    fakeView.setLayoutParams(params);
    fakeView.setId(view.getViewId());
    addView(fakeView, params);
```

Then I create TextView and set it BELOW this view.

```
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mSignaturePlaceHolder.getId());
```

and expect that this text will be below my view. But in practise I have following result. 
[image]

like my view locates at position 0,0. But it draws at neded position. What I do wrong?

Comment: are you sure you are passing `MY VIEW` id in `textParams.addRule` ? and also remove `fakeView.setId(view.getViewId());` because you are trying to set same id for two views

Comment: These views are in different viewgroups,so they may to have equals ids.

Comment: @Raman Branavitski the new TextView needs to be in the same ViewGroup of the other view mentioned in the "below" tag. If it is true, all these views need to have different IDs.

Comment: Of course. You r right. My view and textView are in the same layout and have different ids. Ignore the ids. Everything is all right with them.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textview.getLayoutParams())
                .addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view_id);
```

Comment: I do not need it to be in the center